# Compare dates two columns with null values Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have the following two dataframes.

df_1:

```
order_id   date
123        2020-01-01
456        NULL
789        2020-10-10
135        2020-05-31
```

df_2:

```
order_id   date
123        2020-01-02
456        NULL
789        2020-10-10
135        2020-12-31
```

I am looking to collect in a list all the order_ids as well as update df_2['date'] when the date in my df_2 is greater than the date in df_1.

The output should be an update to df_1:

```
order_id   date
123        2020-01-02
456        NULL
789        2020-10-10
135        2020-12-31
```

and a list with order_id[123,135]

In subsequent requests, it is also possible that the date can change from NaT to date, for example df_2 now equals:

```
order_id   date
123        2020-01-02
456        1999-01-01
789        2020-10-10
135        2020-12-31
246        NaT
468        NaT
```

Therefore df_1 would now equal:

```
order_id   date
123        2020-01-02
456        1999-01-01
789        2020-10-10
135        2020-12-31
```

and the list of order_ids would be [123,456,135]

What I've attempted:

```
if df_2['date'] > df_1['date']:
```

but I am receiving the following message:
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need matching values in both DataFrames before compare, this solution use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), another left join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then set values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
#convert to datetimes if necessary
df_1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['date'])
df_2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['date'])
```

---

```
s = df_2.set_index('order_id')['date']

mapped = df_1['order_id'].map(s)
mask = mapped > df_1['date']

df_1.loc[mask, 'date'] = mapped
print (df_1)
   order_id       date
0       123 2020-01-02
1       456        NaT
2       789 2020-10-10
3       135 2020-12-31

order_id = df_1.loc[mask, 'order_id'].tolist()
print (order_id)
[123, 135]
```

Another idea:

```
df = df_1.merge(df_2, on='order_id', how='left', suffixes=('','_'))

mask = df['date_'] > df['date']
df.loc[mask, 'date'] = df.pop('date_')

print (df)
   order_id       date
0       123 2020-01-02
1       456        NaT
2       789 2020-10-10
3       135 2020-12-31

order_id = df_1.loc[mask, 'order_id'].tolist()
print (order_id)
[123, 135]
```

Comment: This worked as expected but I am now running into an issue where I am not able to compare when NaT is changed. So if NaT is changed to a date I would like to update this value as well. did you have any recommendations there? I ended up using your first suggestion btw and thank you. @jezrael

Comment: @Aldo - Do you think change `mask = mapped > df_1['date']` to `mask = (mapped > df_1['date']) | df_1['date'].isna()` ?

Comment: giving this is a try.. ty

Comment: So this is changing it when NaT is true in both columns. we want to only change it when NaT becomes a new date or when the date gets switched to NaT. There are instances where NaT now has a new date and this needs to updated only for that order_id.

Comment: @Aldo - Is possible see changed data for this? Not sue if understand. Or need  add after my solution `df_1['date'] = df_1['date'].fillna(mapped)` ?

Comment: Would I be able to contact you directly somehow to better explain? So chat room perhaps?

Comment: hmmm, is problem change data in question for see it? Because I am like sample man, the best is working with sample data, because easy verify solution. Now only guess what need.

Comment: I can't type out the example data here because there are character limits within the comments section, that's why I was asking for a different format to communicate with. But if not its no big deal, you've already been extremely helpful and I appreciate it.

Comment: @Aldo - I thin kedit question with sample data ;)

Comment: @Aldo - added after my solution `df_1['date'] = df_1['date'].fillna(mapped)` and working well with new data.

Comment: at which point did you add this line of code?

Comment: @Aldo - It seems I dont understand. I test `mask = (mapped > df_1['date']) | df_1['date'].isna()` wit hnew data and working well, for yo unot?

Comment: Let me update the example from a few minutes with more details

Comment: @Aldo - Ok, please test if not working `mask = (mapped > df_1['date']) | df_1['date'].isna()`

Comment: testing `mask = (mapped > df_1['date']) | df_1['date'].isna() ` and working well for me.

Comment: I've updated the values, and I already tried this and unfortunately, this is capturing all values where df_1['date'] = NaT and df_2['date'] = NaT. I only want to capture it when a specific order_id switches from NaT to a new date.

Comment: @Aldo - Not sure if understand :(

Comment: Ok, no worries... thank you for all your help either way!